# Geocortex Essentials: Read data/web map I don't own from a shared private group on AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online, geocortex, geocortex-essentials

I have data and a web map created and hosted in Org B and shared with me via a private group. I am in Org A.

So I was able to successfully add the shared web map as a site reference, but the data (hosted in Org B) was added with no errors or warnings but it does not render on the map in Manager. I opened the viewer to investigate further and I got a message saying it could not load the layers in question.

I tried to add the layers (hosted in Org B, but shared via a group to Org A, and using the URL from Org A) to the map in Manager directly from their service URL, but GE gives me no errors or warnings again in the Manager and just gets hung on the "Add Map Service" window.

Is it possible for GE to consume data hosted from a separate organization and shared via a private group without linking the Manager to multiple AGOL Organizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. The data was added through http not https, as required by my GE. Thus, I had to manually update it.